# Select min from a given range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following data:

```
 req_id |      detected
------------------------
    420 |       26808302
    420 |       26808303
    420 |       26808305
    420 |       26808306
    422 |       26808302
    425 |       26808303
    422 |       26808305
    425 |       26808306
    420 |       26808365
    420 |       26808366
```

... And i would need to group these records based on their id, selecting just the min values for a given range of 'detected' (+- 20 for example).
This is what i'd be expecting:

```
req_id |      detected
------------------------
    420 |       26808302
    422 |       26808302
    425 |       26808303
    420 |       26808365
```

Is there a way with SQL think of a way to do this, or am i losing my time with this data?

Comment: I just don't understand the question.  Perhaps you can provide a clearer explanation of what "selecting just the min values for a given range of 'detected' (+- 20 for example)" or exactly how the results are related to the input.

Comment: I don't understand the question please provide valid info, I think you need minimum value of detected column according request id , what meaning this line 'detected' (+- 20 for example) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you just want `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(detected) over (partition by id order by detected) as prev_detected
      from t
     ) t
where prev_detected is null or prev_detected < detected - 20;
```

This returns rows where the gap from the previous `detected` is more than 20 -- and should return the results that you specify.